# To click on "X" button which is defined by span tag using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

To click on "X" button which is defined by span tag using selenium python.

The "X" is defined by span and it is not getting clicked.

```
<span class="popup_cancel hide_poup"/>
```

I tried below which is not working

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='popup_cancel hide_poup']").click()
```

Please guide me how to make this work!!

Comment: search for action chains

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "popup_cancel hide_poup"))).click()
```

or

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='popup_cancel hide_poup']"))).click()
```

**Note :** please add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```